# Return boolean if duplicates exist

Tags: sql, boolean, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I return **True** if a table has any duplicate records and **False** if it has none.

> I don't need a count, I don't need to know which rows, all I want to know is if this table has duplicates or not. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to list out columns, then here is one method:

```
select (count(*) <> num_distinct) as has_duplicates
from t cross join
     (select count(*) as num_distinct
      from (select distinct * from t) t
     ) tt;
```

If you have a primary key, then a more efficient method would be:

```
select (count(*) <> count(distinct pk)) as has_duplicates
from t;
```

A relatively efficient method with a primary key would be:

```
select (count(*) = 1) as has_duplicates
from (select t.*
      from t
      where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.pk = t.pk and t2.? <> t.?)
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) t;
```

The `?` is for the column/columns that you care about in terms of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

for one particular column you can use the following - it will return True or False if there are duplicates in the column inside the brackets

```
SELECT  count(id) = count(distinct id)
from t1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 1
FROM T
GROUP BY C1,C2...
```

Comment: This is incorrect, even if the user specifies all the columns, it will return one row for each combination of values. Please make sure next time if your solution actually works.